# How to list all cache names and all column names inside one cache in Apache Ignite 2.1?

Tags: java, sql, ignite

Is there a java code or SQL example to list all caches existing in Apache Ignite?

Also is there a java code or SQL example to list columns within one cache in Apache Ignite?

Answer (score 1):

`org.apache.ignite.Ignite#cacheNames` lists all the available caches.

You can obtain information about columns from `QueryEntries` set for a cache via `CacheConfiguration#setQueryEntities` or `CacheConfiguration#setIndexedTypes`.
Just call `Collection<QueryEntity> queryEntities = cache.getConfiguration(CacheConfiguration.class).getQueryEntities();` and then call `QueryEntity#getFields`on the `QueryEntity` of your interest.

As well you can obtain information about extracted query fields while using `SqlFieldsQuery`.

```
FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(new SqlFieldsQuery(query));
for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getColumnsCount(); ++i) {
    String fieldName = cursor.getFieldName(i);
    // ...
}
```